# Updating date in SQL/VB/Asp.Net

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, date

I'm pretty much a novice at all this. I know bits. Just trying to store a date in an SQL database. I've set it to `06/06/2015` temporarily in code below to see if I can get it to update but it updates it as `01/01/0001`. When I suss it, The value I actually want to store is todays date plus 6 months. EG: if its `31/07/2015` today, I want it to store `31/01/2016`. Can anyone help ? Much appreciated...

**ASPX.VB**

```
Protected Sub imgBtnDatechange_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs) Handles imgBtn.Click
Dim acc As New accounts(Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey)
Dim adjustedDate as Date = "06/06/2015"
acc.UpdateVipEndDate(acc.accountID, acc.adjustedDate)
End Sub
```

**ACCOUNTS.VB**

```
Public Property adjustedDate As Date

Public Sub UpdateVipEndDate(ByVal accountID As Guid, ByVal adjustedDate As Date)
    Dim DBConnect As New DBConn
    Using db As DbConnection = DBConnect.Conn("DBConnectionString")
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = DBConnect.Command(db, "UpdateVipEndDate")
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("accountID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier,       ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = accountID
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("newadjustedDate", SqlDbType.Date,     ParameterDirection.Input)).Value = adjustedDate
        db.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        cmd = Nothing
        db.Dispose()
        db.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

**STORED PROCEDURE**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [UpdateVipEndDate]
@accountID          uniqueidentifier,
@newadjustedDate    date
AS
BEGIN

UPDATE tblAccounts SET [vipEndDate] = @newadjustedDate WHERE [accountID] = @accountID

END
```

Answer (score 1):

You set a date here:

```
Dim adjustedDate as Date = "06/06/2015"
```

But you never *use* that variable anywhere.  Instead, you're using a parameter on the `acc` object:

```
acc.UpdateVipEndDate(acc.accountID, acc.adjustedDate)
```

So, presumably, the `acc.adjustedDate` value is otherwise empty or some default `MinDate` value.

It seems like you're confusing a few things here...

1. If something is a `Date`, use it as a `Date`.  Not as a `String`.
2. If the `UpdateVipEndDate` method is *on* the `acc` object, why do you need to pass it references to its own parameters?  It should be able to access those values internally in the method.

I'm probably getting off point here, though.  The simplest thing, it seems, would be to not use a local variable and use the object member that you use elsewhere:

```
acc.adjustedDate = "06/06/2015"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply David... Oooh I'm a bit lost now. Once I see the solution I'll know exactly what's going on but I've only been learning this a day or two. I know the Stored Procedure works, It's the VB code I can't get my head round yet. If you or anyone can adjust it for me it will be clearer for me to suss out. I'll bake you a cake.. I'm good at that ;-)

Comment: @Eggybread: I'm not sure what else you're looking for.  Did you try my suggestion?  Instead of creating a new local variable to hold the date (what your code is doing), set the date on the object's variable that you're actually passing to the method.

Comment: Sorry, didn't follow you first time but I see what you're saying now. Just tried it and its now saying BC30311: Value of type 'Boolean' cannot be converted to 'Date'.

Comment: Ah.. Used ToString and it worked. Thanks so much David.